# First-order nonlinear ordinary differential eqauation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me to solve the equation $y'=\dfrac{y}{x}\left(\dfrac{xy + 1}{xy - 1}\right)?$ I have been trying a few methods. Thanks.

$P=xy^2+y,$
$Q=-(x^2y-x)$

I tried to make it exact differential equation, and found $M(y)=(xy + 1)^{-4}$. When I multiply $M(y)$ with the original equation. After that, following operations becomes tiresome.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! If you've made some attempts, you should put those in your question along with your thoughts on the question. Otherwise the lack of context is likely to result in this question being placed on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just denote $x y = u$. Then $y = \frac{u}{x}$ and
$$
y' = \frac{u' x - u}{x^2}.
$$
Substitution of these things to the problem leads to
$$
\frac{u' x - u}{x^2} = \frac{u}{x^2} \left(\frac{u + 1}{u - 1}\right),
$$
i.e.
$$
u' x - u = \frac{u (u + 1)}{u - 1},
$$
i.e.
$$
u' x = \frac{2 u^2}{u - 1}.
$$
Now you can proceed with the standard separation of variables.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped a lot.